# Project loaded error after debugging

Tags: c++

EDIT: So took your guys' advice and now my program compiles. But now I can't get it to run because I get these errors.

```
'baseconverter.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\OwnerT\Documents\Visual Studio 2010
\Projects\baseconverter\Debug\baseconverter.exe', Symbols loaded.
'baseconverter.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'baseconverter.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'baseconverter.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'baseconverter.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'baseconverter.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
The program '[5320] baseconverter.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Here's the new updated code. I fixed the std::cout and have eliminated the namespaces, but I think that overloaded the coding.

**converter.h**

```
#ifndef CONVERTER_H
#define CONVERTER_H
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
//This contains the function types needed for
//reading an input
//converting from any base to base10
//convert from base10 to any base
extern int non10num;
extern int bIn;
extern int bOut;
extern int b10num;
extern int Conv;
extern int option;
extern int sum;
extern int num;

#endif
```

**convertion.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include "converter.h"

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int non10num = 0;
int bIn      = 0;
int bOut     = 0;
int b10num   = 0;
int Conv     = 0;
int option   = 0;
int sum      = 0;
int num      = 0;
int main ()
{

//Reinstates the int variables

int pow = 1; 
while (option)
{
sum += b10num * pow;
num /= 10;
pow *= non10num;
}
}
```

**converter.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include "converter.h"

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

extern int non10num;
extern int bIn;
extern int bOut;
extern int b10num;
extern int Conv;
extern int option;
extern int sum;
extern int num;


//This brings us to the menu
void menu()
{
cout << "1. Base to Base" << endl;
cout << "2. Base to Base-10" << endl;
cout << "3. Base-10 to Base" << endl;
cout << "4. Exit" << endl;
cout << "" << endl;
cout << "Choose your option: ";
        cin >> option;
        switch (option)
        {
        case 1: cout << "Enter your integer: "; //Asks for user input
                    cin >> non10num;
                cout << "Enter which base it belongs to: ";
                    cin >> bIn;
                cout << "Enter the base it should be converter: ";
                    cin >> bOut;

                cout << non10num << " in base " << bIn << " is " << non10num%bIn << " in base " << bOut<< endl; //Converts the data
                break;

        case 2: cout << "Enter your integer: ";
                    cin >> non10num;
                cout << "Enter which base it belongs to: ";
                    cin >> bIn;
                cout << non10num << " in base " << bIn << " is " << non10num%10 << " in " << b10num;
                break;

        case 3: cout << "Enter your integer: ";
                    cin >> b10num;
                cout << "Enter which base the integer will be converted: "; cin >> Conv;

                cout << b10num << " in base 10 is " << b10num%10  << " in "<< Conv;
                break;

        case 4: //Exits the menu
            return ;
            break;
            default: 
            cout << "You have entered an invalid option!" << endl;
        }

while (option!=0);
return ;
}
```

Comment: Your new error messages are an issue with your compiler/IDE, not with your code. I'm haven't used Visual Studio since the 90s, so can't be much help, but check you made the right kind of project when you started (i.e. "console application" or something like that, rather than "Win32" or "MFC" or whatever they have these days.) Although the last line `The program '[5320] baseconverter.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0)` seems to indicate that your program executed and exited normally.

Comment: By the way, if your original question was answered to your satisfaction, do feel free to click the checkmark next to the best answer to accept it.

Comment: Yeah, I think your program just ran normally. `main()` just sets `pow` to `1`, never loops because `option` is set to `0`, and then exits. You never seem to called your `menu()` function or anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Define* each one like this in *one* of your cpp files:

`int bIn = 0;`

and then *declare* it like this in all your others:

`extern int bIn;`

As it currently stands, you're violating the One Definition Rule.

Also, right now, you're declaring variables of the same names in `main()` which is going to hide all your global variables in that function, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: It's not an ODR violation, because they all have the same exact declaration (identical order of tokens, including in all types the declaration depends on).  ODR doesn't deal with quantity of definitions, it deals with uniformity.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. My program compiles now, but it terminates whenever I go to debug.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I'm happy to be corrected, but how is defining and initializing the same external identifier in two different translation units not a violation?

Comment: @BenVoigt: In other words, if we were talking about defining a *type* I'd be with you, but we're talking about defining and allocating storage for an object, here. Happy to admit if I'm wrong, but I feel pretty sure you can only do this once for each object in a single program.

Comment: Section 3.2.3 from C++11 seems to cover it: "Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline function *or variable* that is odr-used in that program," (emphasis added) which definitely seems to deal with quantity of definitions.

Comment: I'm not saying multiple definitions are legal -- they aren't.  But when people talk about the "One Definition Rule", they invariably are referring to 3.2p6 "Given such an entity named `D` defined in more than one translation unit, then

— each definition of `D` shall consist of the same sequence of tokens; and ..."

Comment: I think you mean point 5. I can't say I've noticed that people "invariably" mean only that specific point of the ODR (not exactly a reliable authority, but the Wikipedia article doesn't, for instance, and talks about the whole thing).

Answer (score 0):

Don't `#include "convertion.cpp"` in any file. By including it, you are replacing that include line with the contents of the file, so you have declared `non10num` twice in the same program: once in "converter.cpp" (because of the include line) and once in "convertion.cpp". I hope this helps.

Comment: That solved my "already defined" problem, but now it's saying all of my 'cout', 'cin' and 'endl' are undeclared identifiers.

Comment: Don't use `using namespace std;` anyway. Either qualify them all (e.g. `std::cout`) or put things like `using std::cout; using std::cin; using std::endl;` at the top of *each* cpp file where you use them.